# Websocket - Nginx proxy pass 400 Bad Request

Tags: nginx, websocket

I am setting up Websocket in nginx with SSL. This is the example code :

**App code :**

```
...
var conn = new ab.Session('wss://domain.com',
...
```

**nginx.conf :**

```
...
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    #listen       80 default_server;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html/dahz/web;
    index        index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/domain.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
            autoindex  on;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

     }
...
```

Until this step, the Websocket has been connected to the server. but where i try to access https://domain.com eventhough i have been able to access https://domain.com/index.html. there are some 400 error on asset. 
how do i fix the 400 error ?

Comment: One doubt, why are you using autoindex and try_files? I understand the idea of proxy_pass is to pass the control to the webserver on 8080 and not process anything

Comment: i've to comment the autoindex   & try_files. but the page can't open. its not  problem..

Comment: in error.log : $onnect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xxx, server: domain.com, $tream, client: xx.x.xx.xxx, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/", host: "domain.com"

Comment: I've got a configuration using a proxy with SSL and the two headers you added fixed my problem. Are you sure your socket connection isn't fallbacking to http mode? That's what the log says

Comment: `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";` fixed for me, thanks!